# Display all data information JSON in array

Tags: ios, swift, api, uitableview

hello i have a problem I get well the json file in the API

```
▿ 23 elements
  ▿ 0 : 10 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      - key : _id
      - value : 5b9912774a324d25ac5b52d8
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      - key : userid
      - value : 5b76c507af724e6f7538f249
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      - key : __v
      - value : 0
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      - key : internationalFormat
      - value : +224 625 25 92 39
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      - key : firstname
      - value : toto
    ▿ 5 : 2 elements
      - key : lastname
      - value : tata
    ▿ 6 : 2 elements
      - key : countryCode
      - value : GN
    ▿ 7 : 2 elements
      - key : nationalFormat
      - value : 625 25 92 39
    ▿ 8 : 2 elements
      - key : created_at
      - value : 2018-09-12T13:19:51.794Z
    ▿ 9 : 2 elements
      - key : beneficiarynumber
      - value : +224625259239
```

but I can not display all the information of the user (firstname, lastname ..) this is the code I implemented to display all user information

```
   struct Beneficiary {
        let id: Int
        let firstName: String
        let lastName: String
        let beneficiaryNumber: String
        init(_ json: [String: Any]) {
            self.id = json["_id"] as? Int ?? 0
            self.firstName = json["firstname"] as? String ?? ""
            self.lastName = json["lastname"] as? String ?? ""
            self.beneficiaryNumber = json["internationalFormat"] as? String ?? ""
        }
    }

    class HPBeneficiaryViewController {
                    //// list beneficiary /////
                    let token = HPWSLoginManager.shared().saveSuccessResponse.token
                    let idUser = sub["_id"] as! String
                    let url = URL(string: "http://51.38.36.76:40/api/v1/beneficiaries/"+idUser)!
                    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                    request.httpMethod = "GET"
                    request.addValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                        guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
                            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                            return }
                        do {
                            let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: [])
    //                        print(jsonResponse)
                            guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                                return
                            }
                            var model = [Beneficiary]()
                            for dic in jsonArray {
                                model.append(Beneficiary(dic))
                                cellModelArray.append(HPBeneficiaryModel(firstName: model[0].firstName, lastName: model[0].lastName, tel: model[0].beneficiaryNumber, type: .beneficiary))
                            }
    }
 let sectionModel = HPBeneficiarySectionModel(name: "Mes Beneficiaires", modelArray: cellModelArray)
                        self.sectionArray = [sectionModel]
} catch {
                        print("error serializing")
                    }
                    }.resume()
```

but it just displays a loop with the first user information how to recover all users ?? help me please

Comment: Don't parse JSON manually, use `Codable` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain where exactly you have an issue and tell what you have tried so far. (You shouldn't expect us to analyse this code and figure out where it goes wrong. Instead help us as much as possible to understand the issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate issue is this line:

```
cellModelArray.append(HPBeneficiaryModel(firstName: model[0].firstName, lastName: model[0].lastName, tel: model[0].beneficiaryNumber, type: .beneficiary))
```

You always access the first element of the `model` array while adding new elements to the end of the array. You need to use `model.last!` instead of `model[0]`.

However, you should switch to using `Codable` instead of manually parsing a JSON response.

```
struct Beneficiary: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let beneficiaryNumber: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "_id", firstName = "firstname", lastName = "lastname", beneficiaryNumber = "internationalFormat"
    }
}
```

Then make the network request:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
        return
    }
    do {
        let model = try JSONDecoder().decode([Beneficiary].self, from: dataResponse)
        cellModelArray.append(contentsOf: model.map({HPBeneficiaryModel(firstName: $0.firstName, lastName: $0.lastName, tel: $0.beneficiaryNumber, type: .beneficiary)}))
        let sectionModel = HPBeneficiarySectionModel(name: "Mes Beneficiaires", modelArray: cellModelArray)
        self.sectionArray = [sectionModel]
    } catch {
        print("error serializing")
    }
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of these two lines

```
    for dic in jsonArray {
        model.append(Beneficiary(dic))
        cellModelArray.append(HPBeneficiaryModel(firstName: model[0].firstName, lastName: model[0].lastName, tel: model[0].beneficiaryNumber, type: .beneficiary))
     }
```

use these :

```
    for dic in jsonArray {
        model.append(Beneficiary(dic))
        cellModelArray.append(HPBeneficiaryModel(firstName: dic.firstName, lastName: dic.lastName, tel: dic.beneficiaryNumber, type: .beneficiary))
    }
```

You already have an object that is "dic" for each cycle the loop makes. However, you keep accessing the first element of the model `model[0]` which gets you the same object regardless of the current loop..

I would suggest that you also use Codable to parse your JSON. It's much easier and pretty straight forward.
Here's a nice tutorial:
https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1